# React Router nesting

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, nested-routes

i'm trying to use nested routing in react router. But my nesting routig not working.  If that's make diffrence i'm using Typescript.

```
//This is working
<Route exact path={path} component={StudentList}></Route>
//This is not working
<Route path={`${path}/:id`} component={StudentComponent}></Route>
```

I have a module called StudentModule. In module a have two routes like above when i route to
`/students/1` nothing render

I created a sample app on CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-pasteur-n1eq7

To see what's wrong, navigate to students in menu then click student. It's needs to render StudentComponent and writes `Student works` on the screen.

Pls help me what's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In component **StudentModule**, please declare the variable id, I think you have missed it and string literal is understanding the id as general string.
And pass the url like

```
<Route exact path={`${path}/${id}`} component={StudentComponent}></Route>
```

Find the updated code below:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import StudentComponent from "./Student";
import StudentList from "./StudentList";

export default function StudentModule() {
  let { path } = useRouteMatch();
let id = 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(path);
  });
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={path} component={StudentList}></Route>
      <Route exact path={`${path}/${id}`} component={StudentComponent}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

try it, hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

At your main router, you declared

```
  <Route exact path="/students" component={StudentModule} />
```

Because you set path to be `exact` from one hand, and not declare path as `students*`, while navigate to `students/1`, you aren't entering into the `Route` which holds the sub-router at all.